# Display custom products based on form entries

Tags: custom-product-type

I m trying to replicate policybazaar[dot]com for a client. Is it possible to show products based on form filled by a user? The form will contain fields with predefined options. The user fills the fields and on the basis of combination of values of diffrent fields, I wish to show products. I have not used magento so a detailed help with be appreciated, Thanks :)

Comment: You mean some kind of an advanced search?

Comment: not search exactly, get values filled by user, check against db and then display product.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a configurable product. Altho normally used for stuff like color or size it also works great for what you want.

Instead of naming an attribute 'size' just fill out a question as the attribute label and the possible answers as options. I've done it a couple of times before and all that really requires some modification is the product page to be a bit more 'form'-like

More on configurable products you can read here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product

Comment: how do I specify a product for a combination of values filled in form?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a link to information on configurable products. Basically the form is on the product view page. When all options are selected this will result in a specific product